# Passing database data through a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am struggling to pass data that i have gotten from my database through to a detailed view in which shows more information. In my view controller i have got a method GET() which gets the data from the database. I am struggling trying to pass this data through a segue. I have also got a Cell.swift file which consists of four labels. I am simply trying to pass the data that the user clicks on in the table view cell to the detailedviewcontroller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    get()
}
var values:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    get();
}

func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://get.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    TableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}

// This function is called before the segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
    secondViewController.d = "ddd";
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.RecipeName.text = maindata["RecipeName"] as? String
    cell.IngredientsList.text = maindata["IngredientList"] as? String
    cell.Method.text = maindata["Method"] as? String
    cell.Rec.text = maindata["PhotoURL"] as? String

    var urlString = maindata["PhotoURL"] as? String

    var url = NSURL(string: maindata["PhotoURL"]as! String)!

    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!

    cell.DaImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: where is the problem? The same way you set `d` you can set some `values` variable as well.

Comment: bit confused how would i do that?

Comment: The best will be to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then get the item and call to performSegueWithIdentiifer and send the selected item in the sender parameter and on the prepareForSegue grab it and send it to the next view controller (also don't forget to check for segue.identifier value in this method)

Comment: You should use Swift's native `Array` rather than `NSArray`. Also, don't use semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `tableViewCell` inside prepare segue method, by  getting selected row and use that indexPath to get selected cell something like below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SpecialCell

        detailViewController.data = cell?.data
        detailViewController.anyotherdata = cell?.anyotherdata
    }
}
```